# Can't avoid object slicing in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, stdvector, object-slicing

I want to construct a `std::vector` containing objects derived from the `Base` class. I know that I can't directly push the whole object into the `vector` (cause of object slicing) so I use smart pointers. However, it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
struct Base{
    int num1;
    explicit Base(int num1){
        this->num1 = num1;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base{
    int num2;
    explicit Derived(int num1, int num2) : Base(num1){
        this->num2 = num2;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> someList;
    someList.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>(100, 1));
    someList.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>(100, 2));
    std::cout << someList[0]->num2 << std::endl; // <---- Can't access num2 !
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Base>::operator->()` allows you to access members of `Base` only, since the return type is `Base*`; You'll need to do a cast to actually access members of `Derived`. Since you're only accessing a member of `Derived`, the choice of vector template parameter seems questionable. Maybe you could include some detail on what you're trying to do in your program. (This may actually be an XY problem)

Comment: You need a virtual function defined in `Base` and overridden in `Derived`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I'm just trying to populate a `std::vector` with elements derived from `Base`, so e.g. let's call the base class `Dog`, then I may have a vector full of `Beagle` objects or `BorderCollie` objects, but I only know if I'm dealing with Beagles of Border Collies at runtime.

Comment: What kind of virtual function? @n.'pronouns'm.  I'm pretty new to c++

Comment: I would recommend reading about virtual functions and in general about object oriented programming before trying to work with inheritance. It's not a small topic and the comments section is not suitable for explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Derived` objects and their `num2` members are there, but the type system doesn't know that (and in similar code, it might not be certain).

The type of `someList[0]` is `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, so the `->` operator allows naming members of `Base`. In general, a `unique_ptr<Base>` might not point at a `Derived` at all, so this is the safe way.

If the `Base` type were polymorphic, you could use `dynamic_cast` to check if the object really is a `Derived`. To get this working, let's add a virtual destructor to `Base`:

```
struct Base{
    int num1;
    explicit Base(int num1){
        this->num1 = num1;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Then we can do:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> someList;
    someList.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>(100, 1));
    someList.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>(100, 2));
    if (auto* dptr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(someList[0].get()))
        std::cout << dptr->num2 << std::endl;
}
```

For real code, it's considered better design to make use of virtual functions in `Base` rather than using lots of `if(dynamic_cast)` checks.

Comment: Thank you! So in this example how would I "make use of virtual functions in Base" to obtain the same behaviour?

Comment: @ИванКарамазов add a `virtual` method in `Base` that returns an `int`, then have `Derived` override that method to return `num2`. You can then call that method using a `Base*` pointer without needing a type cast.